# Off the shelf component for Signup Validation and Reset

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I use Quarkus and know you can setup login and signup with OIDC. But most sites offer not only OIDC but also standard username/ password registration. So I was wondering if there are standard off the shelf components for following activities:

1. Registering users
2. Sending validation email or 2FA code
3. Accepting the validation/2FA code
4. Resetting forgotten passwords

I am sure there is something but I could not find it. [Quarkus has a component for handling basic auth](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-basic-authentication-tutorial). This does two things:

1. Retrieves of credentials from requests
2. Validate against users in DB
3. Populate the principal
4. Enforce RBAC

The creation of the user, the sending of validation requests, the resetting of passwords, etc. Still remain to be handled and that's what I am wondering if there are standard components or modules out there.

Comment: Have you checked keycloak? It is not a component but a product, but it works well with Quarkus and can manage users.

Answer (score -1):

Quarkus happens to have a side web framework that does all of this: [enter link description here](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-renarde). It is not part of the core Quarkus but it works beautifully.